# How can I use vim regex to replace text when math divide is involved in the expression

Tags: regex, vim, eval

I am using vim to process text like the following

```
0x8000   INDEX1 ....
0x8080   INDEX2 ....
....
0x8800   INDEXn ....
```

I want to use regular expression to get the index number of each line. that is

```
0x8000 ~ 0
0x8080 ~ 1
....
0x8800 ~ n
```

The math evaluation should be (hex - 0x8000) / 0x80. I am trying to using vim regular expression substitution to get the result in line

```
%s/^\(\x\+\)/\=printf("%d", submatch(1) - 0x8000)
```

This will yield

```
0     INDEX0
128   INDEX1
....
2048  INDEXn
```

What I want to do is to further change it to

```
0     INDEX0
1     INDEX1
...
20    INDEXn
```

That is, I want to further divide the first column with an 0x80. Here is when I get the problem.

The original argument is "submatch(1) - 0x8000". I now add an "/ 0x80" to it, which forms

```
%s/^\(\x\+\)/\=printf("%d", (submatch(1) - 0x8000)\/0x80)
```

Now Vim report error

```
Invalid expression: printf("%d", (submatch(1) - 0x8000)\/0x80))
```

It looks like vim meet problem when processing "/". I also tried with a single "/" (without escape), but still fails.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use the separation character in a `sub-replace-expression`.
 From 
`:h sub-replace-expression` :

```
Be careful: The separation character must not appear in the expression!
Consider using a character like "@" or ":".  There is no problem if the result
of the expression contains the separation character.
```

---

Instead, change the separator to no longer match the division operator. E.g., use `#`.

```
:%s#^\(0x\x\+\)#\=printf("%d", (submatch(1) - 0x8000)/0x80)
```

Note that I had to change your regex (specifically `^\(\x\+\)` to `^\(0x\x\+\)`). I don't know why yours works for you, but from  `:h character-classes`, `\x` shouldn't include the trailing `0x` :

```
/\x     \x      \x      hex digit:                      [0-9A-Fa-f]
```

---

Also, your regex is a bit easier to read (to me at least) using very-magic mode (see `:h magic`):

```
:%s#\v^(0x\x+)#\=printf("%d", (submatch(1) - 0x8000)/0x80)
```

Comment: Thanks! That really works. You are right about the "0x", this is my typo in the thread, I actually include it in my real use.